# summing values of a column based on id

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I have a table which keeps the track of users online time. e.g. if a user logs in  at 10:00 and leaves at 10:30 that will be one record with userId, login-time, logout-time and date. user comes again at 11:05 and goes at 11:50.that is another record. i want sum of time for each user for each day. using entity-frame work, c#,
Here is data structure

id     userId     loginTime     logoutTime           date
1           1             10:00                           10:20                      11-06-2015
1           1             10:30                           10:50                      11-06-2015
1           1             09:00                           10:00                      12-06-2015
1           1             10:15                          11:00                      12-06-2015
her is output

for 11-06-2015 it should be   40 minutes
for 12-06-2015 it should be     105

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: Please specify your table structure and your expected output.

Comment: Not directly relevant to your question, but if you're splitting date and time that might get you into trouble when crossing timezones, e.g. if the user logs in before DST changes. I'd recommend you save loginTime and logoutTime as two datetimeoffset fields.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please read [ask].

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL select values sum same ID](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13819769/sql-select-values-sum-same-id)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I created a single table database to mimic the data structure:

```
static void CreateAndSeedDatabase()
{
    Context context = new Context();
    TimeTracker entry1 = new TimeTracker() { UserId = 1, LoginTime = new DateTime(2000, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0), LogoutTime = new DateTime(2000, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0) };
    TimeTracker entry2 = new TimeTracker() { UserId = 1, LoginTime = new DateTime(2000, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0), LogoutTime = new DateTime(2000, 1, 1, 2, 0, 0) };

    TimeTracker entry3 = new TimeTracker() { UserId = 1, LoginTime = new DateTime(2000, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0), LogoutTime = new DateTime(2000, 1, 2, 2, 0, 0) };

    TimeTracker entry4 = new TimeTracker() { UserId = 2, LoginTime = new DateTime(2000, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0), LogoutTime = new DateTime(2000, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0) };

    List<TimeTracker> entryList = new List<TimeTracker>() { entry1, entry2, entry3, entry4 };
    context.TimeTrackers.AddRange(entryList);
    context.SaveChanges();
}

class Context : DbContext
{
    public Context()
    {
        Database.SetInitializer(new CreateDatabaseIfNotExists<Context>());
        Database.Initialize(true);
    }

    public DbSet<TimeTracker> TimeTrackers { get; set; } 
}

public class TimeTracker
{
    public int TimeTrackerId { get; set; }
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public DateTime LoginTime { get; set; }
    public DateTime LogoutTime { get; set; }
}
```

The following picture shows the results within SQL Server:

[image: Data Setup]

Next, I created the following stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GroupByUserAndDate
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT TimeTracker.UserId, CAST(TimeTracker.LogoutTime AS date) AS LogoutDate,  SUM(DATEDIFF(SECOND, TimeTracker.LoginTime, TimeTracker.LogoutTime)) AS TimeSum
    FROM [ef_6_code_first_database_table_not_create.Context].[dbo].[TimeTrackers] AS TimeTracker
    GROUP BY TimeTracker.UserId, CAST(TimeTracker.LogoutTime AS date)
END
```

This produces the following results:

[image: Stored Procedure Results]

Lastly, I call the stored procedure using EntityFramework:

```
static void ExecuteStoredProcedure()
{
    Context context = new Context();
    QueryResult[] results = context.Database.SqlQuery<QueryResult>("dbo.GroupByUserAndDate").ToArray();
}

public class QueryResult
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public DateTime LogoutDate { get; set; }
    public int TimeSum { get; set; }
}
```